# How to properly handle a tokio::try_join! if one of the tasks panics and cleanly abort?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, panic

For the two async functions that I am passing to my `try_join!()`, let's say there's 3 ways that they could panic.

I'm trying to use a `set_hook` to catch the errors but I'm not sure how to do a `match` statement on the panics so I can display a custom error message for each of the ways that they can panic. It looks like `set_hook` takes a `Box(Any)` (?), so I was wondering if there was a way to check the type of Error. Basically I just don't want to do regex on the ErrString.

I'm also not sure what the best way to abort the runtime within each `match` branch. I'm currently using `std::process::exit(0)`.

code looks like:

```
set_hook(Box::new(|panic_info| {
            println!("Thread panicked! {}", panic_info);
            // std::process::exit(0);
        }));

let (result1, result2) = tokio::try_join!(func1, func2); // code that could panic
```

I want to be able to do something like

```
set_hook(Box::new(|panic_info| {
            match panic_info {
                panic_type_1 => { println!("X was invalid, please try using valid X") }
                panic_type_2 => { println!("Y was invalid, please try using valid Y") }
                panic_type_3 => { println!("Z was invalid, please try using valid Z") }
                _ => { println!("Something else happened: {}", panic_info) }
            }
        }));

let (result1, result2) = tokio::try_join!(func1, func2); // code that could panic
```

Comment: Firstly, don't try to use panics for error handling; read the book section on [recoverable errors](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html) (a.k.a. use `Result` if you can). Second, if panicking is something you still want/need to handle, use [`catch_unwind`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.catch_unwind.html) in order to turn a panic into a `Result`; that will still require you to tangle with `Box<dyn Any>` to differentiate reasons for the panic.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with `set_hook`. The future that `tokio::task::spawn*` returns resolves to a `Result` with a [`JoinError`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/struct.JoinError.html) type, which has a `[try_]into_panic` to get the boxed object that was passed to `panic`.

The panic message is stored as a [`Box<dyn Any>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/any/trait.Any.html) which has tons of methods for downcasting it into various types.

Comment: What I've seen in my case is that it won't return and I have to press ctrl+c to abort the execution